# What "jump to original source" Xcode menu item do?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, menuitem

I stumbled upon `Navigate`>`Jump to Original Source` menu item in Xcode and wonder what is it for? I didn't manage to make it active, it's always grayed out.

[Google know nothing about it](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22jump%20to%20original%20source%22%20xcode)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this menu item in Obj-C -> Swift bridge header files.
Place a cursor on Swift method declaration that represents Obj-C method and choose `Navigate`>`Jump to Original Source`, original Obj-C method will be opened.

Can be used with <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>